# Cant connect to superset using athena database

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, amazon-athena, apache-superset

I am new to superset.
Going to Sources **>** Databases for a new connection to my athena.

I have downloaded JDBC driver and writing following connection line:

> awsathena+jdbc://AKIAJ2PKWTZYAPBYKRMQ:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@athena.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:443/default?s3_staging_dir='s3://aws-athena-query-results-831083831535-us-east-1/' as SQLAlchemy URI. First parameter being access key and 2nd being secret key(Modified a bit for privacy)

I am getting the error:

> ERROR: {"error": "Connection failed!\n\nThe error message returned was:\nCan't load plugin: sqlalchemy.dialects:awsathena.jdbc"}

I really wish to explore the open source visualisation using superset on my databases.

Comment: You should never post your credentials.

Answer (score 1):

As per [Superset documentation](https://superset.incubator.apache.org/installation.html#aws-athena), you need to escape/encode at least the s3_staging_dir, i.e.,

```
s3://... -> s3%3A//...
```

Have you followed that step?

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure you have done `pip install "PyAthenaJDBC>1.0.9"` in the same python environment as you start your superset. Try restarting Superset in the same environment.

Answer (score 0):

In my case problem was with the special characters in the `aws_secret_key` and `s3_staging_dir`. I solved it by putting the output of `quote_plus` methods into the URI. No quotes were required.

```
from urllib.parse import quote_plus
secretkey = quote_plus(aws_secret_access_key) 
loc = quote_plus(s3_staging_dir)
```

Further, make sure the schema_name (i.e. database name) already exists in the s3 path. Hope it helps!